# How to backup a dll saved to database in the Plugin Registration Tool for Microsoft CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I need to update an assembly. But I don't have the old assembly anywhere. If something goes wrong I have no way of reverting back to the old assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solves it:

> You can export it as a solution:
>
> 1) Create a new solution named 'Plugin Backup' or something (Settings->Solutions->New)
>
> 2) Add the plugin (Plugin Assemblies -> Add Existing)
>
> 3) Export the solution as an Unmanaged solution (Export Solution)
>
> This will create a solution zip that contains your dll, which you can then re-import using 'Import Solution' if you need to restore to a previous version.

I got the answer from [Scott Durow](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/scott%20durow%20%5Bdevelop1%5D/?ws=usercard-mini) on [http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/e4506653-92e4-4259-b4bc-f15dcd772a46)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your plug-in is stored in the database and not on disk, [this tool](http://blogs.infinite-x.net/2011/06/27/free-utility-released-export-crm-4-0-plugins/) will do the job. Although it says it is for CRM 4.0 I'm pretty sure that it works with CRM 2011 just fine.